# How to validate between two fields in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have two fields. One is min price and another one is max price. I want to have validation that min price should always be less than max price and max price should be greater than min price. In simple positive case, it works fine.

But it's not working for some cases.

Let's say user enter 12 in min and 100 in max. then If user types 123332 or some big number than 100.it does give the error message.

```
<div class="col-md-3" >
<label for="minimumPriceTextbox" class="control-label">{{l("MinPrice")}}</label>
<input type="text"
       [minValue]="0" [maxValue]="test.maxPrice"
       maxlength="17" class="form-control c" id="minimumPriceTextbox"
       name="minimumPriceTextbox"
       placeholder="Minimum Price"
       [value]="test.minPrice"
       [(ngModel)]="test.minPrice"
       #minimumPriceTextbox="ngModel">
<div *ngIf="minimumPriceTextbox?.invalid && (minimumPriceTextbox?.dirty || minimumPriceTextbox?.touched)" class="has-error help-block help-block-error font-red-mint">
    <span> {{l("MinPriceShouldBeLessThanMaxPrice.")}} </span>
</div>
{{test.minPrice}}
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<label for="maximumPriceTextbox" class="control-label">{{l("MaxPrice")}}</label>
<input name="maximumPriceTextbox"
       type="text"
       [minValue]="test.minPrice"
       maxlength="17" class="form-control c" id="maximumPriceTextbox"
       placeholder="Maximum Price"
       [value]="test.maxPrice"
       [(ngModel)]="test.maxPrice"
       #maximumPriceTextbox="ngModel">
<div *ngIf="maximumPriceTextbox?.invalid && (maximumPriceTextbox?.dirty || maximumPriceTextbox?.touched)" class="has-error help-block help-block-error font-red-mint">
    <span> {{l("MaxPriceShouldBeGreaterThanMinPrice.")}} </span>
</div>
{{test.maxPrice}}
</div>
```

`minValue` directive code:

```
import { Directive, forwardRef, Attribute, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';


@Directive({
    selector: '[minValue]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MinValueValidator), multi: true }
    ]
})
export class MinValueValidator implements Validator {

    @Input('minValue') minValue: number;

    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: number]: any } {
        let givenvalue = control.value;
        let validationResult = null;

        let minValue = this.minValue;
        if (minValue && givenvalue < minValue) {
            validationResult = validationResult || {};
            validationResult.minValue = true;
        }

        return validationResult;
    }
}
```

`maxValue` directive code:

```
import { Directive, forwardRef, Attribute, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';


@Directive({
    selector: '[maxValue]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MaxValueValidator), multi: true }
    ]
})
export class MaxValueValidator implements Validator {

    @Input('maxValue') maxValue: number;

    validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: number]: any } {
        let givenvalue = control.value;
        let validationResult = null;

        let maxValue = this.maxValue;
        if (maxValue && givenvalue > maxValue) {
            validationResult = validationResult || {};
            validationResult.maxValue = true;
        }

        return validationResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do cross validation, however it is possible to create your own custom validator directive, the idea is to pass form component names to validator and subscribe for changes of these components within validator:

```
export interface IValidatorFactory
{
    (input:any, key:string):SyncValidatorResult;
}

@Directive({
    selector : 'input[sync]',
    exportAs : 'sync',
    providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => GenericValidator), multi: true}]
})
export class GenericValidator implements AsyncValidator, OnInit
{
    @Input('sync')
    public factory:IValidatorFactory;

    @Input('deps')
    public deps:string[];

    private onChange:() => void;

    private readonly form:FormGroup;

    constructor(form:NgForm)
    {
        this.form = form.form;
    }

    public ngOnInit():any
    {
        //wait for ngmodel created
        setTimeout(() =>
        {
            if(Array.isArray(this.deps) && this.deps.length > 0)
            {
                const values:any = Object.create(null);

                for(const controlName of this.deps)
                {
                    const control = this.form.get(controlName);
                    if(control == null)
                    {
                        console.error('Dependant control was not found', controlName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        control.valueChanges.subscribe(changes =>
                        {
                            if(values[controlName] !== changes)
                            {
                                values[controlName] = changes;
                                this.onChange();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 0);
    }

    public registerOnValidatorChange(fn:() => void):void
    {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    public validate(c:AbstractControl):AsyncValidatorResult;
    public validate(c:AbstractControl):SyncValidatorResult
    {
        return this.validatorFn(c);
    }

    private validatorFn(formControl:AbstractControl):SyncValidatorResult
    {
        if(formControl.value != null && this.factory != null)
        {
            return this.factory(formControl.value, 'syncValidator');
        }
        return null;
    }
}

    public onValidate(c:AbstractControl):ValidatorResult
    {
        return this.validatorFn(c);
    }

    private validatorFn(formControl:AbstractControl):SyncValidatorResult
    {
        if(formControl.value != null && this.factory != null)
        {
            return this.factory(formControl.value, 'syncValidator');
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Template:

```
    <input name="field1" type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.field1" [sync]="validateFields" [deps]="['field2']"></div>
    <input name="field2" type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.field2" [sync]="validateFields" [deps]="['field1']"></div>
```

Component:

```
public validateFields:IValidatorFactory = (value:string, key:string):SyncValidatorResult =>
{
    let result:SyncValidatorResult = null;

    if(...)
    {
        result = Object.create(null);
        result[key] = {
            valid  : false,
            message: 'invalid values'
        };
    }
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a directive, can't you use a simple function ? Something like (sorry, I'll reduce the code to minimum)

```
<input type="number" (input)="checkValidity()" [(ngModel)]="maxValue">
```

In your TS :

```
checkValidity() {
  if (this.maxValue < this.minValue) { /* Set your error here */ }
  else if (this.minValue > this.maxValue) { /* Set your error here */ }
  else { /* Set your other errors, or your validation here */ }
}
```

Comment: My purpose is that the form should not only show error, it should check the validity of form too. by your code it will allow only show error message,

Comment: Well, it's a method for comparing two fields, as you requested. If you want to validate the whole form on every input (which I don't recommend, you should check its validity only when you send it), then you can simply call your validity-checking method in my function, right under the else !

Comment: completely agree with you, but I don't know how to call validate method in angular?

Comment: Well, given your code, you don't have a built-in validation method. What I was suggesting was that you should call your own validation method, where you check, for instance, if the mail is valid, if the age is above 18, and so on.

Comment: Or else, you can use a form builder to create a form group, with validators and custom validators, which is, in my opinion, far more efficient

Comment: problem is to get rid of the errors set after having them set, and after the user having corrected them without loosing the other validation errors.

Comment: @Nadine calling `setErrors` erases the previous errors, so that's not an issue. You can also handle the no-error state in the `else`.

Comment: Checked, I didn't know that setErrors overwrites the others, but actually should have been clear from the naming. I think it is worth mentioning, because when you have standard form Validators like required, max or pattern, you only can "recreate" the errors from those other validators by using updateValueAndValidity, and if you have multiple errors checked in custom functions, you will also need to repeat those validations.

Comment: It is implicit in Angular, you have `set` to assign a new memory reference, and you have `patch` to update a memory reference. Knowledge comes with practice ! And it's mentionned, just above your last comment :)